# Bootstrap toggle footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i try to make footer columns to be hidden on mobile platforms, and when press on title to open. Is there any way to make this with bootstrap without add any javascript?

My Code is:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Company</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Why buy from us</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping &amp; Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>My account</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{store url='customer/account/login/'}}">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{store url='checkout/cart/'}}">View Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent when you already have a solution. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: my code is on footer, all i need is to hide the ul content and remain there only the title, when a customer press on title ul will be show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Bootstrap alone, you mean CSS alone i can give you a solution that i kind of used a while ago

https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/ybgayvL8/

Adding tabindex to the h4 tags with some css did it, But this could be insufficient for crossbrowser dependancy and stuff , use with caution.

```
    <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4 tabindex="0">Company</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
        <h4 tabindex="0">Why buy from us</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping &amp; Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4 tabindex="0">My account</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{store url='customer/account/login/'}}">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{store url='checkout/cart/'}}">View Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css (you might want to put this inside your media query and five-three is for idenntification sakes consider adding a more semantic class name):

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .five-three ul {
        display:none;
    }
    .five-three h4:focus + ul {
        display:block;
    }
    }
```

Comment: thank you but how I can make the content to be hidden only on mobile?

Comment: As i said media Queries. Updated in answer as well as the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You might add the `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` classes to the footer, so it won't show up on screens narrower than 963px.

Comment: I know this but I need to be collapsible, to remain there only the title, that h4 tag

Comment: You may use these classes on the `ul` too. (Or any other element)

Comment: ok before I use some jquery to hide the ul content but is there any way to do this only with bootstrap?

Comment: What you want, i.e. doing something on click, is not possible using only CSS.

Comment: is not about the css, i know that the bootstrap have some things, something like collapsible

Comment: AFAIK there is no solution for this in Bootstrap (by default), I myself would use vanilla JS to achieve this.

Comment: yes I know about this, my last code is something like this:
  jQuery('.footer .footer-cols h4').append('<span class="toggle"></span>');
  jQuery('.footer h4').on("click", function(){
   if (jQuery(this).find('span').attr('class') == 'toggle opened') { jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('opened').parents('.footer-cols').find('.footer-cols-content').slideToggle(); }
   else {
    jQuery(this).find('span').addClass('opened').parents('.footer-cols').find('.footer-cols-content').slideToggle();
   }
  });

Comment: i use toggle function, but is eat a lot of memory, and i need to be something easy, like data-toggle="collapse"

Comment: You can just simply remove the classes which hide it with DOM API, that will be with orders of magnitudes faster than this solution.

Comment: yes but there will be another js script and I don't want

Answer (score 1):

you can use media queries (in css) to hide your columns with a new rule you define.
here an exemple :
html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 hide"> <!-- Pls see that I add a style name : hide -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another thing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css (new stylesheet):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   /*I take max-width: 768px because of bootstrap : sm is for 768px too*/
  .hide {
    display: none !important; /*You don't need !important if you load this stylesheet after you main one*/
  }
}
```